# Structure of object fetched to firebase from GAS Google sheet

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have script tied to Google sheet that collects data from 3 columns (date, userID, value) on the sheet and pass them to object that is then fetched to Firebase DB.
[image: google sheet]

The script correctly push the object into Firebase but I have troubles to achieve structure of data object that I need (so the nodes are correctly structured in Firebase). In the “date” column in the sheet I have date under which I want to group userID:value pair but when I iterate over rows in the sheet it only stores last userID:value pair with given date and not all.

My code:

```
function writeValues() {

// Database reference
const databaseURL = "https://sampledatabaseURL.firebaseio.com/"

const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

// Get spreadsheet, range of data and all values within
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("test");
const range = sheet.getDataRange();
const allValues = range.getValues();

// Get indexes for headers in columns
const headers = {};
allValues[0].forEach(function (value, index) {
    headers[value] = index
});

const dbData = {};

allValues.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) { return }  // skip header row

    dbData[row[headers.date]] = {
        [row[headers.userID]] : row[headers.value]
    }
})

const url = databaseURL + "/test.json?access_token=" + encodeURIComponent(token)
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: 'put',
    payload: JSON.stringify(dbData)
})
Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
}
```

Output JSON file it produces and that’s fetched to Firebase:

```
{
"20180118" : {"userID2" : "value2"},
"20200705" : {"userID4" : "value4"},
"20210324" : {"userID6" : "value6"}
}
```

Desired output structure:

```
{
"20180118" : {"userID1" : "value1", "userID2" : "value2"},
"20200705" : {"userID3" : "value3", "userID4" : "value4"},
"20210324" : {"userID5" : "value5", "userID6" : "value6"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the following situation.

  - From: This image is from your question.

    [image]
  - To: You want to retrieve the following output as the value of `dbData`.

    ```
      {
      "20180118" : {"userID1" : "value1", "userID2" : "value2"},
      "20200705" : {"userID3" : "value3", "userID4" : "value4"},
      "20210324" : {"userID5" : "value5", "userID6" : "value6"}
      }
    ```

In this case, how about the following modidfication? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
const allValues = range.getValues();

// Get indexes for headers in columns
const headers = {};
allValues[0].forEach(function (value, index) {
    headers[value] = index
});

const dbData = {};

allValues.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) { return }  // skip header row

    dbData[row[headers.date]] = {
        [row[headers.userID]] : row[headers.value]
    }
})
```

#### To:

```
const [, ...values] = range.getValues();
const dbData = values.reduce((o, [a,b,c]) => {
  if (!o[a]) o[a] = {};
  o[a][b] = c;
  return o;
}, {});
console.log(dbData)
```

- When above modified script is run for your sample Spreadsheet, the value of `dbData` is the output you expect.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Hi,
that helped solve the problem - thanks a lot for that! I'm not very skilled in JS and had no experience with reduce() so I first spent 1 hour uncovering what is happening behind the scene but I think I understand now. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Petr G Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.